# How to apply exponential moving average decay for variables in pytorch?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I am reading following paper. And it uses EMA decay for variables.
[Bidirectional Attention Flow for Machine Comprehension](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.01603.pdf)

> During training, the moving averages of all weights of the model are
>   maintained with the exponential decay rate of 0.999.

They use TensorFlow and I found the related code of EMA.
https://github.com/allenai/bi-att-flow/blob/master/basic/model.py#L229

In PyTorch, how do I apply EMA to Variables?

Comment: I wanted to add that the author seems to have found a solution here:
https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-apply-exponential-moving-average-decay-for-variables/10856

Answer (score 0):

You can implement an Exponential Moving Average (EMA) for model variables by having a copy of your model with a custom update rule.

First, create a copy of your model to store the moving averages of the parameters:

```
import copy

model = YourModel()
ema_model = copy.deepcopy(model)
```

Then, define the EMA update function, which will update the moving averages of the model parameters after each training step:

```
def update_ema_variables(model, ema_model, ema_decay):
    with torch.no_grad():
        for ema_param, param in zip(ema_model.parameters(), model.parameters()):
            ema_param.data.copy_(ema_param.data * ema_decay + (1 - ema_decay) * param.data)
```

Finally, call the update_ema_variables function in your training loop after each optimization step:

```
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
ema_decay = 0.999

for epoch in range(epochs):
    for batch in data_loader:
        # Perform your forward pass, compute loss, and update model parameters
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(batch)
        loss = criterion(output, batch)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        # Update EMA model
        update_ema_variables(model, ema_model, ema_decay)
```

With this code you can maintain the moving averages of your model's parameters during training. The ema_model will hold the EMA parameters, and you can use it for evaluation or inference.

Alternatively, there are libraries with simple wrapper for this e.g. https://github.com/fadel/pytorch_ema

Answer (score -7):

Moving average is the key concept of momentum in gradient descent.

In [PyTorch document](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/optim.html) you can find:

`optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.1, momentum=0.9)`

Change the parameter `momentum` to the value you want.